# Array of CvScalars

Tags: arrays, opencv, matrix

I am trying to find the mean and standard deviation of certain images.I am using cvAvgSdv command which returns CvScalar values.I want to store the mean and deviations in an array or matrix.Can you please suggest any way to do that other than linked lists.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming C++, why don't you use std::vector? Reference [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/)